# How to chain http request in angular 2 based on the response type

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to make an api call from a remote server but if the request returns an error i wanted to make another request from my local server. I keep getting an error. I was wondering if my idea is doable.

In my service:

```
constructor(private _http: Http) { }
getAll(): Observable<any> {
    let result: any;
    this._http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) => result = <any>response.json())
        .catch(this.getAllFromBackup);

    return result;
}

getAllFromBackup(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

In my component I am subscribing to the response:

```
export class JobComponent implements OnInit {
    allJobs: any;
    statusMasage: string = 'Loading you data...';

    constructor(private _jobService: JobService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this._jobService.getAll()
            .subscribe((jobData) => { console.log(jobData), this.allJobs = jobData },
            (error) => { this.statusMasage = 'There is propblem with the service please try again later.'});
    }

}
```

Comment: `I keep getting an error`, and that is?

Answer (score 2):

Sure your solution could work, but there's an easier way.

From what I understood, you're trying to retry your HTTP request once again in the case it fails, right?

Thankfully, there's a retry() method on Observables.

You could use this:

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
    let result: any;
    this._http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) => result = <any>response.json())
        .retry(1) // this will repeat request once on error
        .catch(() => { console.log('Do something with the 2nd error')});

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I just wanted t pull data from an api but whenever there is a problem with the api, I wanted to pull the data from my local database through a restful service. I see some references retry during subscription.